# Lightning Component quick action not appearing in available actions for Lightning App page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I created a sample Lightning Component quick action as outlined in the documentation, [Configure Components for Custom Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_config_action.htm).

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction">

    <!-- Very simple addition -->

    <ui:inputNumber aura:id="num1"/> +
    <ui:inputNumber aura:id="num2"/>

    <br/>
    <ui:button label="Add" press="{!c.clickAdd}"/>

</aura:component>
```

I then created a global action pointing to my Lightning component. So far, so good.

[image]

The action shows up as expected in the standard layout editor when I view the Salesforce1 & Lightning Actions in either an object page layout or in Global Actions > Publisher Layouts.

[image]

When I add the action to a page layout in this way, to the Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience Actions section of the layout, it appears in Lightning Experience as expected. Yay!

[image]

However, if I create a Lightning "App Page" in Lightning App Builder, my Lightning Component quick action doesn't appear in the list of available actions. All global Create a Record and Log a Call type actions appear, but the Lightning Component action does not.

[image]

[image]

Has anyone been able to add a Lightning Component quick action to their Lightning App pages in Lightning App Builder?

UPDATE: I have tried implementing force:availableForAllPageTypes and force:appHostable (together and separately) - these did not work.

Comment: Can you please share your code to see if all is ok? did you implement force:appHostable?

Comment: I have shared the code and screenshots. I tried implementing - at different times - force:appHostable and flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes (which seemed like the more likely solution since Lightning App pages in Lightning App Builder are flexipages). Neither worked.

Comment: Try adding flexipage:availableForAllPage and see if that helps.

Comment: Tried that (see my previous comment) - didn't help.

Comment: looks like only global actions are available to the quick action from app builder. I replicated the same issue in my dev box.

Comment: I created it as a global action - but it appears that only the Create a Record and Log a Call global actions appear. I'll try it with a Visualforce quick action when I get a chance.

Comment: You are right. I have tried to do exactly what you did and could not succeed. So maybe it is a limitation (for now), or you should add another `implements=fexipage:something` that I cannot find. A workaround for this problem would be to wrap the lightning component inside a VisualForce page, and this page you can easily add as a global action to your page. If you want an example - tell me and I'll post as an answer. good luck!!!

Comment: @shannonsans It looks like this is available now. Please see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't supported in App Builder yet. It's definitely on our radar and is something we'd like to fix in a near term release (safe harbor).

Comment: Just thought of this - since it's basically just a flexipage, could I add it manually through the MD API?

Comment: A year later, it seems still not to be working.

Comment: @ChristianSzandorKnapp It appears to be working now. Please see my answer for more details.

Comment: Still not working. @RobertHyatt's answer is for a regular Create a Record quick action, not a Lightning component quick action.

Comment: 7 years later, still an issue. :-(

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the Metadata API as suggested by @shannonsans

You can manually create a metadata file with the following content (edit caps fields):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QuickAction xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <height>500</height>
    <label>YOUR LABEL</label>
    <lightningComponent>COMPONENT NAME</lightningComponent>
    <optionsCreateFeedItem>false</optionsCreateFeedItem>
    <type>LightningComponent</type>
    <width>-100</width>
</QuickAction>
```

Save the file as OBJECTNAME.ACTIONNAME.quickAction and then deploy.

Super big thanks to @shannonsans for giving us the idea to try.

Comment: old question, but you said you got it to work by manually creating the MD file. How do you specify the objectname, when it's supposed to be a global action ?

Answer (score -2):

I was able to get this to work.

First, go to global actions:

[image]

Then, click "new":

[image]

Then, add what you want it to do; I made a new global action to create a new campaign here:

[image]

Now it shows up as an available action on the flexipage:

[image]

If you are interested in making it happen programmatically, when I pulled from my scratch org with 
`sfdx force:source:pull`,
`quickActions/NewCampaign.quickAction-meta.xml` was generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QuickAction xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <optionsCreateFeedItem>true</optionsCreateFeedItem>
    <quickActionLayout>
        <layoutSectionStyle>TwoColumnsLeftToRight</layoutSectionStyle>
        <quickActionLayoutColumns>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>Name</field>
                <uiBehavior>Required</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>IsActive</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>ParentId</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>Type</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>StartDate</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>EndDate</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>Description</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
        </quickActionLayoutColumns>
        <quickActionLayoutColumns/>
    </quickActionLayout>
    <standardLabel>New</standardLabel>
    <targetObject>Campaign</targetObject>
    <type>Create</type>
</QuickAction>
```

and it was referenced like the built-in quick actions in the flexipage definition:

```
...
    <quickActionList>
        <quickActionListItems>
            <quickActionName>NewCampaign</quickActionName>
        </quickActionListItems>
    </quickActionList>
...
```

Comment: This is a standard "Create a Record" quick action, not a Lightning component quick action. Lightning component quick actions are still not showing up in the list of available actions.